# DialogFlow: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed computing credential metadata

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow Java Client library in my android app, to detect the Intent. Below is the code snippet to perform the operation.

```
    InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials);
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);

    String projectId = ((ServiceAccountCredentials)credentials).getProjectId();
    SessionsSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder();
    SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider
                            (FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                            .build();
    sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings);
    session = SessionName.of(PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID);

    QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder()
                            .setText(TextInput.newBuilder().setText(msg)
                            .setLanguageCode("en-US"))
                            .build();
    DetectIntentRequest detectIntentRequest =DetectIntentRequest.newBuilder()
                                .setSession(session.toString())
                                .setQueryInput(queryInput)
                                .build();
    sessionsClient.detectIntent(detectIntentRequest);
```

But i get the following error

> com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed computing credential metadata

1. I have created a DialogFlow account and it has a valid service account linked to it.
2. Also followed the steps mentioned in the dialog flow link to create a new service account to allow DialogFlow roles.
   https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
 InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials);
 GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
```

Try to use the following environment variables :

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path_to\src\main\resources\service-account.json
```

The SessionsClient should automaticly retrieve the credentials :

```
sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create();
...
sessionsClient.detectIntent(detectIntentRequest);
```

Do not forget to close the channel :

```
sessionsClient.shutdown();
sessionsClient.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: I don't think you can set a runtime environment variable like this when running an Android app.